# How to manipulate the array in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, dynamic-arrays

I've have an array called `$data`. Actually it's a quite big array and it gets generated dynamically. That means it could be small or large. But for your reference I'm printing out a relatively small instance of array `$data`:

```
Array
(
    [op] => edit
    [pt_id] => 4
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [pt_doc_title] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test Document
            [2] => New Joining
            [3] => Happy New Year
        )

    [pt_doc_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
        )

    [pt_doc_file_iname] => Array
        (
            [0] => test_document.docx
            [1] => new_joining.pdf
        )

    [submit] => Update
)
```

I want to manipulate above array(`$data`) in such a way that it should look as follows:

```
Array
(
    [op] => edit
    [pt_id] => 4
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [pt_documents_data] => Array        
        (
      [0] => Array
        (   
            [pt_doc_title] => Test Document
        [pt_doc_id] => 6
        [pt_doc_file_iname] => test_document.docx
        )
      [1] => Array
        (
        [pt_doc_title] => New Joining
        [pt_doc_id] => 7
        [pt_doc_file_iname] => new_joining.pdf
        )
      [2] => Array
                (
        [pt_doc_title] => Over load
        [pt_doc_id] => 
        [pt_doc_file_iname] => 
            )
          )
)
```

But I'm not getting how should I achieve this as I'm relatively new to Array Manipulations in PHP. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: Should the title one begin with 0 or indeed 1?

Comment: @Farkie:I didn't get you. Could you please explain further?

Comment: [pt_doc_title] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test Document
            [2] => New Joining
            [3] => Happy New Year

Comment: Should that be: `    [pt_doc_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test Document
            [1] => New Joining
            [2] => Happy New Year
`

Comment: Can you please describe *in words* what exactly should happen?

Comment: @Farkie:Oh sorry. Yes it should start with 1 only not with zero.

Comment: @deceze:Actually I want to put the things together in one array element for further array manipulation. Now the things are scattered into different elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($array['pt_doc_title'] as $key => $title) {
    $id   = isset($array['pt_doc_id'][$key])         ? $array['pt_doc_id'][$key]         : null;
    $file = isset($array['pt_doc_file_iname'][$key]) ? $array['pt_doc_file_iname'][$key] : null;

    $array['pt_documents_data'][] = array(
        'pt_doc_title'      => $title,
        'pt_doc_id'         => $id,
        'pt_doc_file_iname' => $file
    );
}

unset($array['pt_doc_title'], $array['pt_doc_id'], $array['pt_doc_file_iname']);
```

Something along these lines. You use the keys of `$array['pt_doc_title']` to get the corresponding other two values from the other two arrays, then you group them into a new array `pt_documents_data`.

For a simplified example of the general operation:

```
$array = array(
    'foo' => array('a', 'b', 'c'),
    'bar' => array('x', 'y', 'z')
);

$result = array();

foreach ($array['foo'] as $key => $foo) {
    $result[] = array('foo' => $foo, 'bar' => $array['bar'][$key]);
}

// result: array(array('foo' => 'a', 'bar' => 'x'), array('foo' => 'b', 'bar' => 'y'), ...)
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the `[submit] => Update` pair.

Comment: I'll leave those trivial details to the OP.

Comment: Actually I'm getting the array like this:Array([op] => edit [pt_id] => 4[form_submitted] => yes [submit] => Update  [pt_documents_data] => Array([0] => Array([pt_doc_title] => Test Document [pt_doc_id] => 7[pt_doc_file_iname] => new_joining.pdf)[1] => Array([pt_doc_title] => New Joining [pt_doc_id] => 
                    [pt_doc_file_iname] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [pt_doc_title] => Hallo Jolly
                    [pt_doc_id] => 
                    [pt_doc_file_iname] => 
                )

        )

)

Comment: @PHP Which means... it worked? It didn't? You need more help?

Comment: Actually the issue is as per tyour logic the elements having 0 key in the sub-array [pt_doc_id] and array [pt_doc_file_iname] are not  accessible as the $key has starting value 1. That's why I'm not able to access the pt_doc_id and pt_doc_file_iname with key value zero.

Comment: Then you simply need to do `$key - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, though not in your specific order:

```
foreach ($array['pt_doc_title'] as $id => $title) {
            $new_array = array('pt_doc_title' => $title,
                                'pt_doc_id' => $array['pt_doc_id'][$id-1],
                                'pt_doc_file_iname' => $array['pt_doc_file_iname'][$id-1]
                        );
            $array['pt_documents_data'][] = $new_array;
}

unset($array['pt_doc_title'],$array['pt_doc_id'],$array['pt_doc_file_iname'], $array['update']);
```